# Cell editing finishes on Ctrl-Shift in XMind

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, language-support, xmind

I am using [`XMind`](https://www.xmind.net/xmind8-pro/) on Ubuntu and also am using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> combination to switch languages. Unfortunately, this makes me unable to enter multilinguale text in node title: if I typed something in one language, then pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, the editing finalizes as if I pressed Enter and next any key pressed erases all text in node.

How to overcome?